# Angular: how to send data from child component to parent component?

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular. I've read the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) and five blog posts and it's as clear as mud. I have two templates in my view. The child template has a button. When the user clicks the button I want an element (an instructions card) to show in the parent template. When the user clicks the button again I want the element to not show. I.e., the child button toggles the parent element on and off.

```html
<button (click)="toggleInstructions()">Instructions</button>
```

In my header (child) component I made an output event emitter `sendData`, a boolean variable `showInstructions`, and a function that toggles the `showInstructions` between `true` and `false`.  After logging `showInstructions` (works great!) it calls `sendData` to emit the data. I created a new variable `myData` because I'm confused about the use of `this`.

```js
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  @Output() sendData = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  showInstructions: boolean = false;

  toggleInstructions(myData: boolean) {
    console.log("Clicked!");
    switch (true) {
      case (this.showInstructions === true):
      this.showInstructions = false;
      break;

      case (this.showInstructions === false):
      this.showInstructions = true;
      break;

      default:
      console.log("Error in switch-case.");
    }
    console.log(this.showInstructions);
    myData = this.showInstructions;
    console.log(myData);
    this.sendData.emit(myData);
  }
}
```

In the parent component I imported the child component (`HeaderComponent`) and made a function `toggledInstructions` to receive the data. When I clicked the button nothing is logged.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  toggledInstructions(myData: boolean) {
    console.log("Data coming in!");
    console.log(myData);
  }
}
```

I'm baffled how this is supposed to work. I see nothing in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) that connects the transmitting and receiving functions except that data variable name (`myData`).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: please provide the app.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this ZeroesAndOnes [blog post](https://medium.com/@Zeroesandones/emit-an-event-from-a-child-to-parent-component-in-angular-9-7c3690c75f6) that explained this well. To work through my answer, start with the blog post and spin up its code.

Change `child.component.html` to:

```html
<div style="border: solid 1px gray; padding: 15px; margin-top: 15px;">
    <h2>Child Component</h2>
    <button (click)="clickButton()">Show Element in Parent</button>
</div>
```

Nothing special in the child template. Just a button that triggers a function in the controller.

Change `child.component.ts` to:

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
})
export class ChildComponent {
  showElement: boolean = false;
  @Output() buttonClicked: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  clickButton() {
    console.log("(Child) Value before toggle: " + this.showElement);
    console.log("(Child) Button clicked!");
    switch (true) {
      case (this.showElement === true):
      this.showElement = false;
      break;

      case (this.showElement === false):
      this.showElement = true;
      break;

      default:
      console.log("Error in switch-case.");
    }
    console.log("(Child) Value after toggle: " + this.showElement);
    this.buttonClicked.emit(this.showElement);
  }

}
```

The list of variables starts with `showElement` which is a `boolean` and is initialized `false`, i.e., the parent element is hidden.

Next is another variable that is the first bit of Angular magic. The variable is `buttonClicked` and it has the decorator `@Output()`. This decorator means that the variable will be available outside the controller. The variable is type `EventEmitter<boolean>` and it is assigned a new event emitter. The type can be left off if you prefer a shorter line:

```js
@Output() buttonClicked = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

Next is the function that toggles `showElement` between `true` and `false`. At the bottom of this function is the second bit of Angular magic. The output event is called and `showElement` variable is sent to be emitted by the event emitter.

Now change the parent template `app.component.html` to:

```html
<div style="border: solid 1px gray; padding: 15px;">
  <app-child (buttonClicked)="parentEventHandlerFunction($event)">
  </app-child>
  
  <h1>Parent Component</h1>
  <span><b>Value emitted from child component is:</b></span>
  {{ valueEmittedFromChildComponent }}
  
  <div *ngIf="valueEmittedFromChildComponent"><span style="color: red;"><b>My awesome element!</b></span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

The big Angular magic is in the parent template, specifically in this line:

```html
  <app-child (buttonClicked)="parentEventHandlerFunction($event)">
  </app-child>
```

The directive `app-child` embeds the child template into the parent template. `buttonClicked` is the event emitter in the child controller. `parentEventHandlerFunction` is a function in the parent controller. `$event` is the object sent from the child to the parent. This single line combines parts of the child controller and the parent controller, with an equal sign to connect them. That's the big Angular magic.

Now set up the parent controller `app.component.ts`:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  valueEmittedFromChildComponent: boolean;

  parentEventHandlerFunction(valueEmitted){
    this.valueEmittedFromChildComponent = valueEmitted;
    console.log("(Parent) Value emitted: " + valueEmitted);
  }
}
```

We have one variable named `valueEmittedFromChildComponent` which is a `boolean`. Then we have one function `parentEventHandlerFunction` with one parameter `valueEmitted`. The `$event` object comes in from the magic line in the parent template and is assigned to the local variable `valueEmittedFromChildComponent`.

Going back to the parent template, we display the the local variable `valueEmittedFromChildComponent` and use it in an `*ngIf` to make an element show and hide.

ZeroesAndOne concluded their blog post, "In conclusion, angular makes it extremely easy to create child components that emit data to its parent component using the @Output() decorator." Hah! This is not what I call "extremely easy." In AngularJS, in comparison, the two templates would share one controller. The button in one template binds to a function in the controller, which toggles a variable, which binds to an element in the second template to show and hide an element. The data goes from the first template to a single variable in the controller to the second template. That's "extremely easy."

In Angular, the button in the child template triggers a function in the child controller, the same as AngularJS. But then you need to make an `@Output()` decorator with an event emitter, and call the event emitter from the toggle function. The data is then emitted to the magic line in the parent template, which combines stuff from the child controller and parent controller. Then the data goes to the parent controller, and then back to the parent template to show or hide the target element.

Let's repeat that. When the user clicks the button in the child template, the data goes to the child controller, where a function toggles the value, and then sends the data from the function to an event emitter. The event emitter sends the data to the parent template, which sends the data to the parent controller, which sends the data back to the parent template to show or hide the element. That's not what I call easy.

How would you do this in React? Is React more like AngularJS or Angular?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need `$event` variable to get emitted value:

```
<button (click)="toggleInstructions($event)">Instructions</button>
```

and

```
toggledInstructions(event: boolean) {
    console.log("Data coming in!", myData);
}
```

The event binding `(fooevent)` allows to bind to DOM events and to `EventEmitter` events

**UPDATE:**

An example of work code:

**ChildComponent.ts:**

```
@Output() public onFooClicked = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

showMenu() {
  this.onFooClicked .emit(true);
}
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
<foo (onFooClicked)="onClicked($event)">
</foo>

onClicked(event: boolean) {
    console.log(`Somebody clicked`, event);
}
```

[In addition, there is a great article how to pass data.](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-ways-to-share-data-between-angular-components-d656a7eb7f96)

Comment: Maybe, but something else must be wrong. I added ```$event``` and I'm not seeing "Data coming in!" in the console. The documentation doesn't use ```$event```.

Comment: @ThomasDavidKehoe have you added `event` as parameter of your method? Please, see my updated answer.